# How can I get the NuGet package version programmatically from a NuGet feed?

Tags: c#, nuget

First off, of all the NuGet code, I'm trying to figure out which one to reference.

The main question is, given a NuGet *package name*, is there a programmatic way to retrieve the versions from the NuGet feed and also the latest version for general consumption?

For example, given a package name of ILMerge, it would be nice to get the latest package version of 2.13.307.

```
// Pseudo code, makes a lot of assumptions about NuGet programmatic interfaces
PackageRef currentVersion = nugetlib.getpackageinfo(args[0]);
Console.WriteLine("Package Id: '{0}':", pkg.Id);
Console.WriteLine("  Current version: {0}", pkg.Version);
Console.WriteLine("  Available versions: {0}", String.Join(",",pkg.Versions.Select(_=>_)));
```

Comment: Something that can help you, maybe? http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/05/retrieving-nuget-package.html

Comment: @DavidBrabant I think the page your link was pointing to got sold. Now it triggers a lot of redirects and leads to shops etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [NuGet core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/):

```
string packageID = "ILMerge";

// Connect to the official package repository
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");
var version =repo.FindPackagesById(packageID).Max(p=>p.Version);
```

Reference: *[Play with Packages, programmatically!](http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html)*

Comment: Note that NuGet.Core is now deprecated - it's recommended to instead use [NuGet.Protocol](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Protocol/) instead ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk)).

Comment: It's nice to see that `Version` implements `IComparable<T>` so that it can be retrieved directly.

Answer (score 4):

There exist a quite nice NuGet API to accomplish both.

a) Retrieving the NuGet package versions (for the Newtonsoft.Json package in following example):

```
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/Newtonsoft.Json/index.json
```

b) Downloading a certain version of the NuGet package - e.g.

```
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/utf8json/1.3.7/utf8json.1.3.7.nupkg
```

Please try to copy the URL to the browser and you could see the results of the examples...

To get more information about API, please visit the
*[Package Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource)*

The following code example could read the versions of a package (using the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) NuGet package which provides HttpContent's  ReadAsAsync<T> extension for parsing the JSON result to an appropriate class - the VersionsResponse in this example)

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace GetNuGetVer
{
    class VersionsResponse
    {
        public string[] Versions { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var packageName = "Enums.NET";
            var url = $"https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/{packageName}/index.json";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            var versionsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<VersionsResponse>();
            var lastVersion = versionsResponse.Versions[^1]; //(length-1)
            // And so on ..
        }
    }
}
```

To get rid of [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client) (with dependency to [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)), System.Text.Json can be used out of the box (since .NET Core 3.0) with code changes as follows:

```
        using System.Text.Json;
        ...
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var versionsResponseBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        var versionsResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<VersionsResponse>(versionsResponseBytes, options);
        var lastVersion = versionsResponse.Versions[^1]; //(length-1)
```

or just a different JSON parser based on your own preferences.

Comment: The https://michaelscodingspot.com/the-battle-of-c-to-json-serializers-in-net-core-3/ could help choosing the right JSON parser ..

Comment: That url is not working for me and returns
```
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:a42c4f2e-001e-0001-6f0e-c1e279000000 Time:2022-09-05T10:04:06.0211970Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 2):

As described on [NuGet2](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2), Nuget.Core is for version 2 of NuGet.

Version 3 of the NuGet client library has moved to Nuget.Client. See the NuGet API v3 documentation for more information.

*[NuGet Client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk)*

Answer (score 0):

The answers in this thread either no longer work, return only partial results, or have been deprecated.

I found a working solution, which is to use the newer NuGet API version:

GET `https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/{your package name here, lowercase}/index.json`

For example to find the package information for the RavenDB.Identity package, I'd call it like this:

GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/ravendb.identity/index.json

Note that the package name must be converted to lowercase, otherwise you'll get an error.

The actual latest package version number can be fetched like this:

```js
let results = await fetch("https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/ravendb.identity/index.json");
let json = await results.json();
let package = json.items[0];
let latestPackage = package.items[package.items.length - 1];
let version = latestPackage.catalogEntry.version; // returns a string like "8.0.7"
```

Here's a working JS snippet that shows the latest version of a package:

```js
async function fetchLatestVersion() {
   let results = await fetch("https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/ravendb.identity/index.json");
   let json = await results.json();
   let package = json.items[0];
   let latestPackage = package.items[package.items.length - 1];
   let version = latestPackage.catalogEntry.version;

   document.querySelector("#results").innerText = `The latest version of the RavenDB.Identity package is ${version}`;
}

setTimeout(() => fetchLatestVersion(), 1000);
```

```html
<div id="results">Fetching results...</div>
```